# How to programmatically simulate a double-tap on a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My app has a `UIWebView` that displays HTML emails. If I zoom in on the content and then double-tap on it a couple of times, the email content eventually gets resized so that it all fits on the screen again.

I'd like to programmatically reproduce this resizing behavior (I want to be able to call a function that re-scales the content so that it all fits on the screen); calling `sizeToFit` on the web view does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the `CGRect` you want to scale it to, then you can use,

```
- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

As `UIWebView` is scrollable, So I guess you should be able to do this.

Apparently your `UIWebView` should have an iVar named [scrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). So, if your `UIWebView` object name is `webView`. just do something like, below code might not be 100% syntactically correct. But you must have got the idea.

```
[webView.scrollView zoomToRect:CGMakeRect(0,0,0,0) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hmm, that at least has some effect on things, but zooming to CGRectZero like that makes it zoom to its maximum size. I want to actually zoom out, so that the entire email fits within the given width.

Comment: I have found link, which has bit of a work but it might help you to synthesize tap events. See : http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html